# Is it possible to expose certain variables to the Unity inspector given a condition?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the Inspector to show me only 1 serialized field depending on a selected enum type, is this possible? I've linked my current script below as an example to what I mean.

This is the code I've written up to now:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PaletteObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] PaletteObjectType paletteObjectType;

    [SerializeField] CustomTile customTile;
    [SerializeField] MaterialTile materialTile;
    [SerializeField] NewAnaglpyh anaglyphTile;
    [SerializeField] EffectObject effectObject;

    public enum PaletteObjectType
    {
        CustomTile,
        MaterialTile,
        AnaglyphTile,
        EffectObject
    }

    // Code to expose only 1 field
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an editor script for your class to draw it in Inspector.
Well, there are generally 3 different ways:

- Use the SerializedObject / SerializedProperty mechanics instead of using the “target” field. This is the recommended solution
- Add some sort of public property or getter/setter to your class so the editor can actually access it. This of course indirectly makes the field editable by others.
- Another way would be to use reflection to edit the private member field.

If it’s important for you that the field should not be exposed (directly or indirectly) the second solution is out. If you insist in using the old way to write custom inspectors (using “target” or “targets”) the only way to change private or protected members is to use reflection.

However, the recommended way would be to use the serializedObject of the Editor. You would use FindProperty to get a SerializedProperty back. This can be used to modify the serialized data of that field. Here is an example of a class:

```C#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(PaletteObject))]
public class PaletteObjectEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty paletteObjectTypeProp;
    private SerializedProperty customTileProp;
    private SerializedProperty materialTileProp;
    private SerializedProperty anaglyphTileProp;
    private SerializedProperty effectObjectProp;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        paletteObjectTypeProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("paletteObjectType");
        customTileProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("customTile");
        materialTileProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("materialTile");
        anaglyphTileProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("anaglyphTile");
        effectObjectProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("effectObject");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(paletteObjectTypeProp);

        PaletteObject.PaletteObjectType paletteType = (PaletteObject.PaletteObjectType)paletteObjectTypeProp.enumValueIndex;

        switch (paletteType)
        {
            case PaletteObject.PaletteObjectType.CustomTile:
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(customTileProp);
                break;
            case PaletteObject.PaletteObjectType.MaterialTile:
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(materialTileProp);
                break;
            case PaletteObject.PaletteObjectType.AnaglyphTile:
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(anaglyphTileProp);
                break;
            case PaletteObject.PaletteObjectType.EffectObject:
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(effectObjectProp);
                break;
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, I just wrote it and used it as an example. It may not work, but I think the point is clear. Or maybe it will be)).

Just create a similar one and place it under the Editor folder. If you haven't Editor folder create the new one under the Assets folder.

Look at [the official Unity doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-HowTo-CreateCustomInspector.html).